# What is the advantage of UnityContainer.Resolve over Activator.CreateInstance?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container, activator

I'm just getting started with Unity. I am still wondering what its advantages are.

`UnityContainer().Resolve<T>()` which can return 
a concrete instance of the type that is registered for the generic type `T`.

I think I can also use `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()`.

`Activator` is a built-in class in the .NET Framework, so I am wondering what the distinct feature for Unity is?

Comment: Read any tutorial on dependency injection, and you'll have your answer...

Comment: Besides, Activator.CreateInstance is *slow*, and cannot map interfaces to concrete types. It is useless for dependency injection

Answer (score 4):

MSDN states these as the advantages of Unity Container:

> 1. Simplified object creation, especially for hierarchical object structures and dependencies
> 2. Abstraction of requirements; this allows developers to specify dependencies at run time or in configuration and simplify management of crosscutting concerns
> 3. Increased flexibility by deferring component configuration to the container
> 4. Service location capability; this allows clients to store or cache the container
> 5. Instance and type interception.

Here's the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647202.aspx).