# Unity Framework vs Activator.CreateInstance

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am looking to do something simple as instantiating a class dynammically from a config file where the config file stores a list of type names. I was wondering if I should use Unity Framework or simply just use the Activator.CreateInstance.  What is the major differences?

sample of what I want to do:

```
LIST myList = Config.GetSection... blah blah

foreach(item in in mylist) {
   IPlugIn x = (IPlugIn)Activator.CreateInstance(item.myPlugInTypeFromConfig,myassembly);

   x.Start(); 
}
```

in my case it seems like I do not need the Unity Framework and can get by with just the activator.

Comment: If you're just using strings to specify the type, `Activator.CreateInstance` will need a second string that specifies the assembly where the type is located: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4

Comment: You'll also need to cast the result as an IPlugin.

Comment: Understood. The code above is just psdo code..

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11075574/what-is-the-advantage-of-unitycontainer-resolve-over-activator-createinstance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental difference is that Unity (or any DI container) can actually manage your dependencies. Activator.CreateInstance just creates instances.

What if you have some types that have constructor parameters and some that don't? Or properties you want set? The container will recurse down the object graph and figure out what values should be put into those constructor parameters or properties. Activator.CreateInstance doesn't do that.

The container manages object lifetime. What if for some types you always want the same instance for type A, but a new one every type for B? It's trivial to do this with a container, you'll have to do it yourself for Activator.CreateInstance.

If all you're doing is "new up this list of types from the config file with no parameters" you're right, you don't need a container. Once you get beyond that, a container brings a lot more power to the table.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use Unity if you had numerous classes that are going to utilize a component.  Dependency Injection occurs at constructor time in those cases.

However it is not, IMHO, a repository for a plug-in architecture.  Looks to me like you are doing what you need to do just fine (though you need a cast and the assembly name), with one exception.  Plug in architectures typically use ConfigurationManager to control the loading of the plugins.

For a real good article on this type of architecture you can read [this article](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/implementing-a-plug-in-architecture-in-c/184403942) on Dr. Dobbs.